# Elastic search resuts for analyzer field does not match

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-analyzers

I have a fuzzy analyzer on addresss field with following mapping and data

```
PUT test_fuzzy
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "max_ngram_diff": "40",
      "mapping": {
        "total_fields": {
          "limit": "2000"
        }
      },
      "number_of_shards": "3",
      "max_result_window": "15000",
      "analysis": {
        "filter": {
          "autocomplete": {
            "type": "ngram",
            "min_gram": "1",
            "max_gram": "40"
          }
        },
        "normalizer": {
          "lowercase_normalizer": {
            "filter": ["lowercase"]
          }
        },
        "analyzer": {
          "autocomplete": {
            "filter": ["lowercase", "autocomplete"],
            "tokenizer": "whitespace"
          },
          "autocomplete_search": {
            "filter": ["lowercase"],
            "tokenizer": "whitespace"
          }
        }
      },
      "number_of_replicas": "0"
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": "true",
    "dynamic_templates": [
      {
        "named_analyzers": {
          "match": "address",
          "match_mapping_type": "string",
          "mapping": {
            "analyzer": "autocomplete",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "ignore_above": 256,
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            },
            "search_analyzer": "autocomplete_search",
            "type": "text"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "properties": {
      "address": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
        "search_analyzer": "autocomplete_search",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "identifier": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Sample data to be ingested

```
 POST test_fuzzy/_bulk
    { "index": { "_id": "1" } }
    { "address": "1136 N Madison Ave", "identifier": 1 }
    { "index": { "_id": "2" } }
    { "address": "7135 Madison Ave W", "identifier": 2 }
    { "index": { "_id": "3" } }
    { "address": "1333 Madison Ave", "identifier": 3 }
    { "index": { "_id": "4" } }
    { "address": "1303 Madison Ave", "identifier": 4 }
    { "index": { "_id": "5" } }
    { "address": "6138 Madison Ave", "identifier": 5 }
    { "index": { "_id": "6" } }
    { "address": "1373 E Madison Ave", "identifier": 6 }
    { "index": { "_id": "7" } }
    { "address": "1333 E Madison Ave Ste 200", "identifier": 7 }
    { "index": { "_id": "8" } }
    { "address": "1311 Madison Ave", "identifier": 8 }
    { "index": { "_id": "9" } }
    { "address": "132 Madison Ave", "identifier": null }
    { "index": { "_id": "10" } }
    { "address": "1213 Madison Ave", "identifier": null }
    { "index": { "_id": "11" } }
    { "address": "413 Madison Ave", "identifier": null }
    { "index": { "_id": "12" } }
    { "address": "134 W Madison Ave", "identifier": null }
    { "index": { "_id": "13" } }
    { "address": "5138 Madison Ave", "identifier": null }
    { "index": { "_id": "14" } }
    { "address": "513 Madison Ave", "identifier": null }
    { "index": { "_id": "15" } }
    { "address": "1330 Madison Ave", "identifier": null }
    { "index": { "_id": "16" } }
    { "address": "13 Madison Ave", "identifier": null }
    { "index": { "_id": "17" } }
    { "address": "130 Madison Ave", "identifier": null }
    { "index": { "_id": "18" } }
    { "address": "131 W Madison Ave", "identifier": null }
```

When we search on 13 Madison Ave we wanted the document matching to it to appear first vs document which are least matching showing below that

Currently 6138 Madison Ave shows up as the first document in the ouput instead of 13 Madison Ave

Query used for Search

```
GET test_fuzzy/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "should": [
                    {
                      "match": {
                        "address": {
                          "query": "13 Madison Ave",
                          "operator": "OR",
                          "prefix_length": 0,
                          "max_expansions": 50,
                          "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
                          "lenient": false,
                          "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
                          "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
                          "boost": 1
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ],
                  "adjust_pure_negative": true,
                  "boost": 1
                }
              }
            ],
            "adjust_pure_negative": true,
            "boost": 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see where you have [`fuzziness` enabled](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#fuzziness) in your query

Comment: which analyzer should i use to get desired output as mention above

Comment: I haven't tested, but I think simply giving a boost to the exact match might do the trick. [This is the query](https://imgur.com/a/slTKtuz) I would try

Comment: i allready had a boost of 1 in my query , i do see that you match and match phase prefix query ,is that required to get desierd output wherein 13 Madison Ave comes as the first document and the remaining matches below that in the output

Comment: Boost 1 doesn't do anything in your case. The combo must/should is how you boost matching results in the should clause. Best is to try it out

Comment: query posted https://imgur.com/a/slTKtuz did not work either